# Isometries between dual factor space and annihilator

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space and $Y$ a closed subspace of $X$ and $Y^0=\{f \in X^*|f(x)=0,\forall y \in Y\}$.

Prove that $Y^0$ is isometricaly isomorphic with $(X/Y)^*$.

I have to find  a function specifically between $Y^0 $ and $(X/Y)^*$.

One idea is the function $S: Y^0 \longrightarrow (X/Y)^*$ such that $S_{f}(x+Y)=f(x)$ but i have a difficult time to proved that it is bounded and an isometry.

Can someone help me please or give another idea for an bijection?

Thnak you in advance.

Comment: I believe, it is not that difficult to calculate the norm of $S_f$ and compare it with the norm of $f$. You just have to keep track in which space the norms are to be calculated. But perhaps this approach might be easier for you: The natural map $X \to X/Y$ induces a map $(X/Y)^* \to X^*$. What is its norm and what is its image?

Comment: I have to find a map from the dual of the fasctor space to annihilator

Comment: Since you are supposed to find an isomorphism, it does not matter in which direction it goes. Once you have an isomorphism $(X/Y)^* \to Y^0$ you can always take the inverse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We assume that $Y \neq X$.

Let $x+ Y \in X/Y$ with $\lVert x+Y \rVert \leq 1$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, there is $y \in Y$ with $\lVert x-y \rVert \leq 1 + \epsilon$. Now
$$
 \lvert S(f)(x+Y)\rvert = \lvert f(x) \rvert = \lvert f(x-y)\rvert \leq (1+ \epsilon) \lVert f \rVert.
$$
This shows that $\lVert S \rVert \leq 1$. To show that $\lVert S \rVert \geq 1$ pick some $x \in X \setminus Y$ with $\lVert x \rVert \leq 1$ (this ensures $\lVert x + Y \rVert \leq 1$). Now we apply a standard Hahn-Banach argument: There exists a functional $f \in X^*$ with $f(Y) = \{0\}$, $f(x) = 1$ and $\lVert f \rVert \leq 1$. Then $\lvert S(f)(x +Y) \rvert = \lvert f(x) \rvert = 1$ and hence $\lVert S(f) \rVert \geq 1$  and so $\lVert S \rVert \geq 1$.

It is clear, that $S$ is bijective.